# Is there a C++ variable type that imitates a temporary?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, temporary

This is really a terribly silly question to which the answer is probably a simple "no", but I'm going to ask in case there is because it would be quite nice.

I can do this, behaviour is exactly as desired:

```
struct A { int x; };

A inc(A a) {
    a.x += 1;
    return a;
}

inc({ 1 });
```

where the fact that `{ 1 }` is a temporary forces that it won't be reused, because it has been left invalid by `inc()` (because of the use of the move constructor -- please correct me if I am wrong about this!).

But what if I am bad at remembering what `{ 1 }` was supposed to stand for, so I make a variable for it, but I still want to force the requirement that it can't be used twice (I'm trying to make it just like a temporary, but named):

```
A a = { 1 };
inc(a);
inc(a);
```

No variation of reference type for `a` will lead the compiler to complain about the double use -- but the move constructor has been precluded by `a` not being a temporary.

Is there a solution?

Comment: Not sure how much it will help, but you could technically build a `UseOnce<T>` with an `operator T` (or `get` function) that gives an error the second time it's called.

Comment: Just curious - can you give an example where this "use once" behavior is useful? Where would you use this?

Comment: In effect, you want the type of `a` to change after it is used in particular ways.  This is not supported in C++ -- variable types are constant over their scope.  There is a name for it, however... but I don't remember it.

Answer (score 12):

I don't think there's a data type for that, but you can use a minimal nested block to limit the scope of the variable - I do this quite often in my code:

```
{
  A a = { 1 };
  inc(a);
}
inc(a);  //error, `a` is not in scope
```

Answer (score 1):

You're describing pretty much the functionality of `std::move` :

```
A a { 1 };
inc(std::move(a));
```

And no, the compiler cannot enforce single-use:

```
A a { 1 };
for (int i = 0; i != 1000; ++i)
  if (g(i)) // Only signature is known, not runtime behavior.
     inc(std::move(a));
```

Answer (score 0):

A (possible) fix is to declare `inc` to take an rvalue reference specifically:

```
A inc(A&& a)
{
    a.x += 1;
    return a;
}
```

When calling it with an lvalue, it will then need to be moved explicitly with `std::move` to compile:

```
A a = {1};
inc(a);    // Error: cannot bind lvalue to rvalue
inc(std::move(a));  // Ok
```

The compiler won't complain about the double use, however, the (explicit) use of `std::move` should tip off anyone reading the code to not use `a` again.

Answer (score 0):

You could use ref qualifier and then use it like so.

```
struct A
{
    A(int i): i_(i) {std::cout << "hello "<<i<<"\n"; }
    A inc() && {return A(++i_); }     //ref qualified incrementor. so it can be called only on temporaries. 
    friend int access( A a );    // to access the value
    A& operator=( const A& ) = delete;// don't allow copy
private :
    int i_;
};

int access( A a )
{
    return a.i_;
}
```

//use case

```
int main()
{
    //A a{5};    //this becomes useless. only use is to get the value..
    A b = A(10).inc();
    //b.inc();    //not possible
    //b = A( 12 ).inc();    //not possible
    std::cout << "\n val = "<<access( b );
return 0;
}
```

but this makes your struct a Non-POD.

also this is available in gcc > 4.8.1.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to detect object are used as temporary in runtime.

[this](https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/blob/b2624cd00e53604315c2b0946ad38d97dc4fd77e/mfbt/GuardObjects.h) is how Mozilla implemented it

Copied from above link. You can search `MOZ_DECL_USE_GUARD_OBJECT_NOTIFIER` in their [git repo](https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev) for example usage

```
/* -*- Mode: C++; tab-width: 8; indent-tabs-mode: nil; c-basic-offset: 2 -*- */
/* vim: set ts=8 sts=2 et sw=2 tw=80: */
/* This Source Code Form is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public
 * License, v. 2.0. If a copy of the MPL was not distributed with this
 * file, You can obtain one at http://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/. */

/* Implementation of macros to ensure correct use of RAII Auto* objects. */

#ifndef mozilla_GuardObjects_h
#define mozilla_GuardObjects_h

#include "mozilla/Assertions.h"
#include "mozilla/NullPtr.h"
#include "mozilla/Types.h"

#ifdef __cplusplus

#ifdef DEBUG

namespace mozilla {
namespace detail {

/*
 * The following classes are designed to cause assertions to detect
 * inadvertent use of guard objects as temporaries. In other words,
 * when we have a guard object whose only purpose is its constructor and
 * destructor (and is never otherwise referenced), the intended use
 * might be:
 *
 *   AutoRestore savePainting(mIsPainting);
 *
 * but is is easy to accidentally write:
 *
 *   AutoRestore(mIsPainting);
 *
 * which compiles just fine, but runs the destructor well before the
 * intended time.
 *
 * They work by adding (#ifdef DEBUG) an additional parameter to the
 * guard object's constructor, with a default value, so that users of
 * the guard object's API do not need to do anything. The default value
 * of this parameter is a temporary object. C++ (ISO/IEC 14882:1998),
 * section 12.2 [class.temporary], clauses 4 and 5 seem to assume a
 * guarantee that temporaries are destroyed in the reverse of their
 * construction order, but I actually can't find a statement that that
 * is true in the general case (beyond the two specific cases mentioned
 * there). However, it seems to be true.
 *
 * These classes are intended to be used only via the macros immediately
 * below them:
 *
 *   MOZ_DECL_USE_GUARD_OBJECT_NOTIFIER declares (ifdef DEBUG) a member
 *     variable, and should be put where a declaration of a private
 *     member variable would be placed.
 *   MOZ_GUARD_OBJECT_NOTIFIER_PARAM should be placed at the end of the
 *     parameters to each constructor of the guard object; it declares
 *     (ifdef DEBUG) an additional parameter. (But use the *_ONLY_PARAM
 *     variant for constructors that take no other parameters.)
 *   MOZ_GUARD_OBJECT_NOTIFIER_PARAM_IN_IMPL should likewise be used in
 *     the implementation of such constructors when they are not inline.
 *   MOZ_GUARD_OBJECT_NOTIFIER_PARAM_TO_PARENT should be used in
 *     the implementation of such constructors to pass the parameter to
 *     a base class that also uses these macros
 *   MOZ_GUARD_OBJECT_NOTIFIER_INIT is a statement that belongs in each
 *     constructor. It uses the parameter declared by
 *     MOZ_GUARD_OBJECT_NOTIFIER_PARAM.
 *
 * For more details, and examples of using these macros, see
 * https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_RAII_classes_in_Mozilla
 */
class MOZ_EXPORT GuardObjectNotifier
{
  private:
    bool* statementDone;

  public:
    GuardObjectNotifier() : statementDone(nullptr) { }

    ~GuardObjectNotifier() {
      *statementDone = true;
    }

    void setStatementDone(bool* statementIsDone) {
      statementDone = statementIsDone;
    }
};

class MOZ_EXPORT GuardObjectNotificationReceiver
{
  private:
    bool statementDone;

  public:
    GuardObjectNotificationReceiver() : statementDone(false) { }

    ~GuardObjectNotificationReceiver() {
      /*
       * Assert that the guard object was not used as a temporary.  (Note that
       * this assert might also fire if init is not called because the guard
       * object's implementation is not using the above macros correctly.)
       */
      MOZ_ASSERT(statementDone);
    }

    void init(const GuardObjectNotifier& constNotifier) {
      /*
       * constNotifier is passed as a const reference so that we can pass a
       * temporary, but we really intend it as non-const.
       */
      GuardObjectNotifier& notifier = const_cast<GuardObjectNotifier&>(constNotifier);
      notifier.setStatementDone(&statementDone);
    }
};

} /* namespace detail */
} /* namespace mozilla */

#endif /* DEBUG */

#ifdef DEBUG
#  define MOZ_DECL_USE_GUARD_OBJECT_NOTIFIER \
     mozilla::detail::GuardObjectNotificationReceiver _mCheckNotUsedAsTemporary;
#  define MOZ_GUARD_OBJECT_NOTIFIER_PARAM \
     , const mozilla::detail::GuardObjectNotifier& _notifier = \
         mozilla::detail::GuardObjectNotifier()
#  define MOZ_GUARD_OBJECT_NOTIFIER_ONLY_PARAM \
     const mozilla::detail::GuardObjectNotifier& _notifier = \
         mozilla::detail::GuardObjectNotifier()
#  define MOZ_GUARD_OBJECT_NOTIFIER_PARAM_IN_IMPL \
     , const mozilla::detail::GuardObjectNotifier& _notifier
#  define MOZ_GUARD_OBJECT_NOTIFIER_ONLY_PARAM_IN_IMPL \
     const mozilla::detail::GuardObjectNotifier& _notifier
#  define MOZ_GUARD_OBJECT_NOTIFIER_PARAM_TO_PARENT \
     , _notifier
#  define MOZ_GUARD_OBJECT_NOTIFIER_ONLY_PARAM_TO_PARENT \
       _notifier
#  define MOZ_GUARD_OBJECT_NOTIFIER_INIT \
     do { _mCheckNotUsedAsTemporary.init(_notifier); } while (0)
#else
#  define MOZ_DECL_USE_GUARD_OBJECT_NOTIFIER
#  define MOZ_GUARD_OBJECT_NOTIFIER_PARAM
#  define MOZ_GUARD_OBJECT_NOTIFIER_ONLY_PARAM
#  define MOZ_GUARD_OBJECT_NOTIFIER_PARAM_IN_IMPL
#  define MOZ_GUARD_OBJECT_NOTIFIER_ONLY_PARAM_IN_IMPL
#  define MOZ_GUARD_OBJECT_NOTIFIER_ONLY_PARAM_TO_PARENT
#  define MOZ_GUARD_OBJECT_NOTIFIER_PARAM_TO_PARENT
#  define MOZ_GUARD_OBJECT_NOTIFIER_INIT do { } while (0)
#endif

#endif /* __cplusplus */

#endif /* mozilla_GuardObjects_h */
```